# Python 3: Jump to next User while creating user-journey

Tags: python, for-loop

i'm having a maybe small problem but i actually can't figure out a solution.

My Data looks like this:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c66et.png)

And i want to create a journey, which led to a conversion, like this:

1: a > b > a > b

2: c > b > a > a

But, at the moment, the result looks like this:

1: a > b > a > b

2: a > b > c > b > a > a

The second one gets some journey spots from the first user, which i don't want.

**My Question is**: how can i group the journey by visid?

**My Code:**

```
transition_matrix = list()
counter = 0
journey = ''
order_id_flag = False
for row in time_data:
    # Set cust_visid and order information
    current_cust_id = row['cust_visid'] if row['cust_visid'] else 0
    netto = row['netto'] if row['netto'] else 0
    menge = row['menge'] if row['menge'] else 0
    buytype = row['buytype'] if row['buytype'] else 0
    if row['marketing_campaign']:  # check if marketing_campaign filled
        # Extract Touchpoint
        touch_point = re.search(r'(\w+)\.', row['marketing_campaign']).group(1)
        # Add to User-Journey
        journey += touch_point + ' > '
    if row['js_order_id']:  # if an order id exists
        order_id_flag = True  # set flag for filled js_order_id
    if order_id_flag:  # check if js_order_id was filled in previous iteration
        transition_matrix.append([current_cust_id, journey.strip(' > '), menge, netto, buytype])  # add to list
        # Reset Variables
        journey = ''
        order_id_flag = False
        current_cust_id = ''
```

Comment: you need to keep maintain track of current cuspomer id , which you passed and `    if row['marketing_campaign']:  # check if marketing_campaign filled
` for this you need to add that part here , once campain failed then add the customer id in list where yu are kkep storing the proceed id and then not to go further with that id and proceed with the next customer id

Comment: i'm not quite sure how to do this, could you assist in updating my code so i get an idea how to do this?